# How to change the Backcolor of TitleBar on DockWindow?

Tags: c#, winforms, docking, dockpanel

I have to color the `TitleBar` of DockWindow. I can able to color the normal `winform Titlebar color`..but I don't know how to change the color of `dockwindow titlebar` if it is docked right,left,top,bottom.

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCPAINT)
        {
            IntPtr hdc = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
            if ((int)hdc != 0)
            {
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc);
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(0, 0, 4800, 23));
                    //(0, 0, 400, 252));
                g.Flush();
                ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hdc);
            }
        }
    }
```

By using this i can able to paint the titlebar of Normal winform..But i cant do this same for Dockwindow

Comment: Where did you get the DockWindow class? It is not part of .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Drawing Custom Borders in Windows Forms](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/) project from *codeplex*. This project is a small library that extends Windows Forms with **ability to customize the windows's non-client area**.

Comment: You can learn how to customize the windows's non-client area like `TitleBar`

Comment: @ Ria just see on top pls..i made a code for normal winform so that i can able to change the title bar of Winform..but if i made the same thing for dockwindow its not working